# Galaxy Nexus density issues

Tags: screen, galaxy

I am developing a application for Nexus S and Galaxy Nexus.
The screen size in Portrait mode are
Nexus S 480x800
Galaxy Nexus 720x1280

The default MDPI screen is 320x480.
Now all my values of margin and borders are multiplied by the density factor if given in dp/dip

So for Nexus S its a exact mapping 320x1.5 = 480.
However, for Galaxy Nexus its a inappropriate 320x2.0 = 640.

So instead of creating a separate layout folder and adding the values in px so that i can achieve exact pixel perfect screen since galaxy nexus is my only xhdpi device that i am suppose to support.

Is there any other option where i can modify the screen density of the system and make it 2.25 for further calculations?

Really disappointed to see a flagship google product behaving this erratically.

BR,
Jayshil

Answer (score 0):

[Maybe this article will be helpful](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) especially the part about `-h<N>dp`/`w<N>dp` and `sw<N>dp` folders.